# Matlab warning('error') produces not enough arguments error

Tags: matlab

I was trying to use the `warning()` function with a warning message. When I try `warning('random message')` it works perfectly fine. But if I change the string to `error` instead, I get an error saying it doesn't have enough input arguments:

```
warning('error')
Error using warning
Not enough input arguments.
```

Is there something special about the word `error` that prevents me from using it as a message?

I am using `2014b`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the `'error'` flag is a special undocumented option that requires an additional input (a [message identifier](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/capture-information-about-errors.html#bq9tdlq-1)). It is used for trapping/catching warnings as errors. See [this Undocumented Matlab post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/trapping-warnings-efficiently) and [this MathWorks Newsgroup posting](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/158768).

This issue can be replicated in R2015a as well. Perhaps this useful option should be documented or maybe `warning('error')` with no message identifier should just work as expected. You might consider [filing a service request](http://www.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/contact_us/?s_tid=gn_cntus) with The MathWorks.

However, it's probably a good habit to use the the two-input form of [`warning`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/warning.html) (and `error`) with the initial message ID. For example:

```
warning('MyFunction1:MyWarningName1','error')
```

or

```
warning('MyLibrary:MyFunction2:MyWarningName2','error')
```

Comment: Thanks @horchler, I was quite curious about this one!

Comment: Great deep Matlab knowledge here!